# parse nested json in arrays like a tree swifty json

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have this json like a tree

```
{
    "6": {
        "id": "1269",
        "text": "Electronics",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "1414",
                "text": " Computers",
                "parent_id": "1269",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "1415",
                        "text": " Barebone Computers",
                        "parent_id": "1414"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1416",
                        "text": " Computer Servers",
                        "parent_id": "1414"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1417",
                        "text": " Desktop Computers",
                        "parent_id": "1414"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1423",
                        "text": " Laptops",
                        "parent_id": "1414"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1425",
                        "text": " Tablet Computers",
                        "parent_id": "1414"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1426",
                        "text": " Thin & Zero Clients",
                        "parent_id": "1414",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "1428",
                                "text": " Zero Client Computers",
                                "parent_id": "1426"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

*Each children field has another children field and so on. This json is about categories of products. Could you help me how can I parse it in* ***SwiftyJson and Alamofire***?

> I have experience in iOS Swift but this json format I have seen the
> first time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this is a json that has a number of object like a "6" but there are more than ones generated by back end. These object have another objects and children field as you can see that looks like a tree. I want to parse it a put it in a list of categories of products. Could you give me an idea please?

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a `Codable` struct which has an array of itself. I made `children` optional so that the bottom children do not need to reference more children.

You could also write your own custom encoder/decoder implementation so that it just makes `children` an empty array instead.

Your `Codable` structs will look something like this:

```
struct Categories: Codable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case six = "6"
    }

    let six: Product
}

struct Product: Codable {
    let id: String
    let text: String
    let parent_id: String
    let children: [Product]?
}
```

Decoding:

```
let json = """
{
    "6": {
        /* ... */
    }
}
"""

do {
    let data = Data(json.utf8)
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Categories.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```